# Using REGEXP_REPLACE in Update MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, sql-update, prestashop, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

Having this field in my database "description" (MariaDB, PHPMyAdmin):

```
<ul>
<li><a href="https://onedomain.com/name-of-product-18-8433290610079.html">Product 1 </a></li>
<li><a href="https://onedomain.com/name-of-product-15-8433290610079.html">Product 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to update it to this (notice categoryName of IdProduct):

```
<ul>
<li><a href="https://newdomain.com/category-name-IdProduct18/18-name-of-product.html">Product 1</a></li>
<li><a href="https://newdomain.com/category-name-IdProduct15/15-name-of-product.html">Product 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have this query that picks up the **pattern correctly** (IdProduct = this pattern **([0-9]{1,5})** ) and the **IdProduct correctly** (**second '\2'**) , the problem comes when making the subquery inside the concat expression since *it doesn't pick up the value of IdProduct* correctly ((**first '\2'**) in subquery).
It works if I put a literal value. For example 1.
`WHERE p3.id_product = 1`

Here is my code:

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang pl
LEFT JOIN ps_product p ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang cl2 ON (p.id_category_default = cl2.id_category)
SET pl.description = REGEXP_REPLACE(pl.description, '<a href="https://onedomain.com/(.*)-([0-9]{1,5})(?:-.*.html|.html)', 
CONCAT('<a href="https://newdomain.com/'
, Replace((SELECT LOWER(cl3.name) FROM ps_product p3 LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang cl3 ON (cl3.id_category = p3.id_category_default) 
WHERE p3.id_product = '\\2'), ' ', '-') 
, '/' , '\\2', '-' , Replace(LOWER(pl.name), ' ', '-') , '.html'))
```

I tried with this and it does not work for me either:
`WHERE p3.id_product = CAST('\\2' AS UNSIGNED)`

I have also tried doing another subquey inside of `WHERE p3.id_product = (subquery)` but it returns only the first link found in the description (in this case productId=18) in all cases.
Here is my code and result:

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang pl
LEFT JOIN ps_product p ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang cl2 ON (p.id_category_default = cl2.id_category)
SET pl.description = REGEXP_REPLACE(pl.description, '<a href="https://onedomain.com/(.*)-([0-9]{1,5})(?:-.*.html|.html)', 
CONCAT('<a href="https://newdomain.com/'
, Replace((SELECT LOWER(cl3.name) FROM ps_product p3 LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang cl3 ON (cl3.id_category = p3.id_category_default) 
WHERE p3.id_product = 
(SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(pl2.description, '<a href="https://onedomain.com/(.*)-([0-9]{1,5})(?:-.*.html|.html)'), '<a href="https://onedomain.com/(.*)-([0-9]{1,5})(?:-.*.html|.html)', '\\2')
FROM ps_product_lang pl2 WHERE pl.id_product = pl2.id_product)), ' ', '-') 
, '/' , '\\2', '-' , Replace(LOWER(pl.name), ' ', '-') , '.html'))
```

Result **(notice both category's names match category-name-IdProduct18)**:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="https://newdomain.com/category-name-IdProduct18/18-name-of-product.html">Product 1</a></li>
<li><a href="https://newdomain.com/category-name-IdProduct18/15-name-of-product.html">Product 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `\\2` is only valid as a string passed to the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function. It's not valid as a subquery identifier. You'll probably need a separate regex function in the subquery or anything else not passes to `REGEXP_REPLACE`

Comment: Can I use the information captured with REGEXP in some way? I could make a REGEX function as a subquery but I need to use the information from the link. Thanks.